# Maximum of continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let f be a continuous function and non decreasing , can we write
$$f(\max(a,b))=\max(f(a),f(b))$$.

Comment: Have you tried even a few examples? Though [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n4ggyagjgc) is a Desmos demo you can play with I suppose

Comment: Here the function is non decreasing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is non-decreasing then since $a\leq max(a,b)$ and $b\leq max(a,b)$, we have $f(a) \leq f(max(a,b))$ and $f(b)\leq f(max(a,b))$. So $max(f(a) ,f(b))\leq f(max(a,b))$.

The other side of the inequality always holds for any function you don't even need the assumption of non-decreasing since $max(a,b)\in ${a,b} so $f(max(a,b))\in ${f(a),f(b)}, and therefore $f(max(a,b)) \leq max(f(a),f(b))$ for any function.

With both inequalities we get $max(f(a) ,f(b))= f(max(a,b))$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $f(x)$ is non-decreasing, then for $c_1\le c_2$, we have $f(c_1)\le f(c_2)$. Hence $$f(\max(a,b))=\begin{cases}
f(a), & a\ge b\\
f(b), & a<b
\end{cases}$$
Note that $$\begin{cases}
f(a)\ge f(b), & a\ge b\\
f(b)\ge f(a), & a<b
\end{cases}$$ So we conclude that
$$f(\max(a,b))=\begin{cases}
\max(f(a),f(b)), & a\ge b\\
\max(f(a),f(b)), & a<b
\end{cases}$$
and hence $f(\max(a,b))=\max(f(a),f(b))$.